# OPNET getting current nodes height

Tags: opnet

I am using OPNET 15, with tmm,

Looking for a way to print the node current height (from sea level)

any known function to use in the C code, or other way? didnt find no help on the web or documentary

Answer (score 0):

Height is a attribute of a node. op_ima_attr_get() can get the height value of a node. It is very easy.

Comment: `op_ima_obj_attr_get(node_objid, "altitude", &alt)` Then you can get the height of a give node model.